# How to check status of data inserted from android to Datastore Google App Engine (JAVA) programmatically?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, rest

I am able to insert data from android app to Datastore, How to check the response status

for example status 200 OK means data is inserted, how to get this status ?

```
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        photo.encodeBlobImage(byteArray);
        photo.setName("Sherlock");
        photo.setName("sherlock");
        photo.setType("image/jpeg");
        photo.setId((long)8232);
        Photoendpoint.Builder builder = new Photoendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                 new JacksonFactory(),
                    null);
        builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);

        Photoendpoint endpoint = builder.build();

        endpoint.insertphoto(photo).execute();
```

This inserts a photo from android to Datastore, and throws exception if not inserted . but i want to know, if data is inserted how to let user know about that ?

Comment: Ask yourself this,what if you get the 200 status code,but nothing was written to GAE?